# MS SQL with Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-update

In the script, the issue is that the Register-ObjectEvent command is being executed inside a loop for each job, but the event registration is being overwritten in each iteration. As a result, only the event for the last job is registered.

```
$connectionstring = "Server=localhost;Database=testDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionstring
$connection.Open()
$jobs = @()
$testOutput = "C:\Users\tarik.gacanovic\Desktop\outfile.txt"

$query1 = "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $connectionstring -Query $query1

$count = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tasks WHERE Enabled='1'"

`$maxConcurrentJobs = 5
$jobsTotalresult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'localhost' -Database 'testDB' -Query $count
$jobsTotal = $jobsTotalresult.Column1

$SQLQueryID = "SELECT ID FROM Tasks WHERE Enabled=1"
$SQLIDCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand ($SQLQueryID, $connection)

$SQLQuerySELECT = "SELECT ExecPath, Param1, Param2, Param3 FROM Tasks WHERE Enabled=1"
$SQLselectCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand ($SQLQuerySELECT, $connection)

$tID = $SQLIDCommand.ExecuteScalar()
$SQLReader = $SQLselectCommand.ExecuteReader()

$data = @()
while ($SQLReader.Read()) {
    $row = @{
        ExecPath = $SQLReader.GetString(0)
        Param1 = $SQLReader.GetString(1)
        Param2 = $SQLReader.GetString(2)
        Param3 = $SQLReader.GetString(3)
    }
    $data += New-Object PSObject -Property $row
    $jobsTotal = $data.Count
}
$SQLReader.Close()
$q = 0

function JobCompleted($receivedState, $jobID) {
    Write-Host 'JOBCOMPLETED WITH' $receivedState

    if ($receivedState.State -eq 'Completed') {
        $Status = 2
        $Note = $jobID
        $Finished = $job.PSEndTime
        $ID = $jobID
        $SQLQueryUPDATE = "UPDATE TaskLogs SET Status=$Status, Finished='$Finished' WHERE ID=$ID"
        $SQLUPDATEcmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SQLQueryUPDATE, $connection)
        $SQLUPDATEcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        $SQLQueryUPDATE | Out-File -FilePath $testOutput -Append
    } elseif ($receivedState.State -eq 'Failed') {
        $Status = 3
        #$Note="Task failed"
    } elseif ($receivedState.State -ne 'Completed' -and $receivedState.State -ne 'Failed') {
        $Status = 9
        #$Note="NOT DEFINED"
    }
}

foreach ($currow in $data) {
    while (($jobs | Where-Object { $_.State -eq 'Running' }).Count -ge $maxConcurrentJobs) {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
    }

    $env:Path = $currow.ExecPath
    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { & $env:Path }
    $jobs += $job

    $jobID = $job.Id
    if ($job.State -eq 'Running') {
        $Status = 1
        $Note = "R--, " + $job.Name
        $Created = $job.PSBeginTime
    }

    $SQLQueryWRITE = "INSERT INTO TaskLogs(ID, tID, Status, Created, Finished, Note) VALUES ($jobID, $tID, $Status, GETDATE(), NULL, '$Note')"
    $SQLWRITEcmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SQLQueryWRITE, $connection)
    $SQLWRITEcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    $SQLQueryWRITE | Out-File -FilePath $testOutput -Append

    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $job -EventName StateChanged -Action {
        $currentState = $EventArgs.JobStateInfo
        JobCompleted $currentState $jobID
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $eventsubscriber.SourceIdentifier
    }
}

# Wait for all jobs to complete
$jobs | Wait-Job | Out-Null

$connection.Close()`
```

I need to update each row with its finish time accordingly but the for loop overwrites the job id with the last one in the batch so I the only row that gets updated is that one. I am not sure how to fix this and any insight would be helpful! Thanks

Comment: why are you unregistering the event? Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $eventsubscriber.SourceIdentifier